# OrientDB MATCH query with negative (NOT) pattern matching

Tags: sql, regex, orientdb

I am building a SQL query in OrientDB and querying records which DO NOT contain the words with a wildcard. How can I design a regex expression for that ?

Let's say for this example the word is `"hello"`

How can I write a query such that any records with word `"hello"` are ignored and the result contains the records which do not contain the matched word.

Example:

```
SELECT from V Where name MATCHES '[regex here]'
```

How can I use a negative match pattern in OrientDB? It seems that this is not mentioned in the manual. (regex is mentioned on page 1108 of 1331 of OrientDB-Manual.pdf)

Comment: `^(?!.*hello).*` or use a sql _NOT_ keyword if there is such a thing with this NOT `^.*hello` AND `^.+` which selects the field value

Answer (score 0):

As of **OrientDB 3.03** this is possible: [see the documentation](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/sql/SQL-Match.html#negative-not-patterns).

An example:

```sql
/* Let's create a class TEST that has V as superclass */
CREATE CLASS TEST EXTENDS V
CREATE PROPERTY TEST.name STRING (MANDATORY TRUE)
/* Let's create two vertices */
CREATE VERTEX TEST SET name = 'a'
CREATE VERTEX TEST SET name = 'b'
/* Now let's match TEST.name where name is NOT 'a' */
SELECT expand(*) FROM (MATCH {class: TEST, as:result, where:(name <> "a")} RETURN result)
```

This returns:

```
"result": [
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#374:0",
        "@version": 1,
        "@class": "TEST",
        "name": "b"
    }
]
```

Which is exactly what you asked (match all records *not equal* to a statement)